# Get and install Nvidia GeForce 8400 GS driver

Tags: nvidia

Recently, I changed my OS kernel from 10.04 to 11.10 (bugs), but after doing it, the video driver for the 8400 GS disappeared (was there in 10.04). I worked out the same procedure I did to install it in 10.04, mainly,

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove nvidia-current
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install nvidia-current
```

but it didn't work even though the commands seemed to install the driver without problems. Right now my machine is working with the standard drivers, as shown.

```
williepabon@WP-WrkStation:~$ sudo lshw -C display
[sudo] password for williepabon: 
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: nVidia Corporation
       vendor: nVidia Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:de000000-deffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:cc80(size=128) memory:dfc00000-dfc7ffff
```

Any suggestions to correct the problem? Thanks

Still waiting for additional help to resolve this. Did what was suggested below, but then, I got stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved. Removed the driver again and did a re-install using the hardware Drivers sub-menu, chose the recommended Nvidia driver from the list, and clicked activate. That did it. Thanks for the help received.

Comment: Having the same problem in 13.04. What do you mean by "hardware Drivers sub-menu"? Where is that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to install them from [here](http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-ia32-295.33-driver.html)? I've had that before where the drivers in the repo don't work but those did. (Link is for 32bit just go [here](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/indexsg.aspx?lang=en-us) if that's not the case)

Comment: Downloaded the file from Nvidia. It's a shell script. Don't have experience running those. First try, get message saying that I need to run as root on terminal. Second try. Get a message saying: "  ERROR: You appear to be running an X server; please exit X before            
         installing." Don't know how to do either of above. Help.

Comment: Wooohooo! Worked to download the drivers directly from nvidia.com, would have been the last place I'd look. Thanks!

Comment: @williepabon run `sudo stop lightdm`, then hit CTRL + ALT + F2, log in and run the installer again (with sudo).

Answer (score 0):

There is a rather radical way I used to do this:

- Save all open files and close all programs
- Press Ctrl-Alt-F2
- Login as root on the console screen
- type "killall -9 kdm" (KDE) or "killall -9 gdm" (Gnome)
- type "killall -9 Xorg"
- "cd" to the location of the nvidia driver and execute it
- type "reboot"

(**)
If everthing goes well, the driver should be installed and everything is working.

If not, you have to boot in recovery mode and manually replace the X config file with the backup created by the nvidia driver installer and reboot again. That is the "tricky" part. After reboot there may appear some questions about configuration. From my experience it's guessing ;) , because not all changes are always applied (wrong permissions?) and others seem to be ignored/not working. But maybe that's been fixed by now or I have been doing something wrong.

Another (more approved) way would be to boot directly to command line and excecute the driver installer. After that, goto (**)

Comment: My experience with Ubuntu is not enough to do radical things. I learned how to run a shell script, and I got the message as explained on my previous comment. But I don't know how to stop the X server and turn it on again. And, I'm not sure if after installing the driver using the shell script, everything will work automatically as it does when you install using the Ubuntu repos (as I did when I had the 10.04 kernel). Thanks for the help.