# Ubuntu can't detect my Nvidia graphics card

Tags: nvidia, system-info

In system details, I can't find information about my graphics card. I have installed graphics driver using *Additional drivers*.

My graphics card is Nvidia 8400GS desktop version with 512 MB DDR2 memory integrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- What kind of error is reported when you try to install via the "Additional Drivers" panel?
- Have you tried to install the drivers via the official nvidia download site?
- Have you checked X.org is working correctly?
- Have you checked your kernel modules and current hardware "reports"?

This is a possible duplicate of another question:

- [Get and install Nvidia GeForce 8400 GS driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115477/get-and-install-nvidia-geforce-8400-gs-driver)

Comment: 1.no error occurred 2.no.  3.no i haven't checked yet. 4.no i didn't check..........